# Usage of Вот именно!

Tags: словоупотребление

I always thought this meant That's right! -or- Exactly! In response to someone coming up with a correct answer or statement. However, recently, I had the following exchange, in which it was intimated that I misused it:

---

**СОБЕСЕДНИК:** Привет! У меня вопрос: "Proper nouns are normally invariant for number: most are singular, but a few, referring for instance to mountain ranges or groups of islands, are plural (e.g. Hebrides)" "invariant for number" значит неизменны, в единственном или множественном числе. Я правильно понимаю?

**Я:** Вот именно!

**СОБЕСЕДНИК:** Только по-русски лучше сказать «Именно!». Если употреблять это слово. А лучше, если хочется сказать что-то необычное, ну то есть не просто «да, правильно», сказать «В точку!» (это как попасть точно в цель, такое значение).

---

That led me to think that I've been misusing Вот именно for a long time. So my question is When *do* you use it? What was wrong with my use of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, **`Вот именно!`** isn't meant to be a response to a question, but a form of unsolicited approval of a statement.

It doesn't have to bear a grumbling tone, it can be expressed enthusiastically, in which case it has connotations of **`See? THAT'S what i'm talking about!`**

Answer (score 2):

The **вот** particle adds a grumbling tone to the expression:

-- Опять на обед капуста, лучше бы мяса дали!

-- Вот именно.

-- Cabbage again. I'd like some meat much better!

-- My thought exactly.

It may also sound a bit sarcastic:

-- Уже 11, пора мне вставать.

-- Вот именно!

-- It's 11 already. Time for me to get up from bed.

-- Nice of you to remember that.

The word **именно** alone will not have these connotations if said in neutral (not grumbling or sarcastic) tone of voice, but anyway it sounds old fashioned to me.

**Именно так** -  is a formal and polite way to express that you're totally agree/support what was just said.

Answer (score 2):

You misused it, but the version **именно!** wouldn't improve the answer: it's just a colloquial simplification of **вот именно!** or **именно так!** in the meaning of confirmation, and that simplification doesn't belong to sophisticated style of speech (it's an *incomplete* expression). The expression **вот именно!** is suitable when you hear a correct judgment and want to use it for making your own point on its basis. If you just want to approve someone's point, **именно так!** is better since it never expresses irony, which is possible with **вот именно!**. Another suggestion ("*да, правильно*") was correct. You could also answer that question "*Безусловно!*", "*Конечно*", "*Совершенно верно*".  "**В точку!**" would better fit a situation where the other person has just made an unexpectedly good guess.